# React hooks: proper way to use useEffect to replace componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am coming over from class styled React components and learning hooks.  Can I just use `useEffect` how I would would use `componentDidMount` lifecycle method?  For example, can I import a function and just call it within `useEffect()` to mimic how `componentDidMount` would work?

```
import { myFunc } from './importedFuncs';

export default function User() {
    useEffect(() => {
        myFunc();
    });
```

Comment: `useEffect` without a dependency array, as in your example, is an equivalent of `componentDidMount` AND `componentDidUpdate`. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html If you want to use it as just `componentDidMount`, add an empty array `...}, []);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React - useEffect hook - componentDidMount to useEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56249151/react-useeffect-hook-componentdidmount-to-useeffect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an `useEffect` equivalent to `componentDidMount`, use the empty array `[]` as the second argument. An empty dependency list ensures the function is executed just once, on the first render.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect(() => {//some code}, [])` to mimic the old `componentDidMount` function. `some code` will only run once on the first render. You can read [this article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) to better understand the `useEffect` hook.