# How to setState to prevState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, state

When I press a button

```
<Pressable
            onPress={() => {
              this.onPressHandler();
            }}>
```

I want to setState to its previous value, but it doesn't happen

```
onPressHandler = () => {
    this.setState(
      prevState => (
        {
          data: prevState.data
        }
      )
    );
  };
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How specifically are you observing that this "doesn't happen"?  You're setting a value to *itself*, what result are you expecting to observe?

Comment: Are you asking how to maintain a history of changes to state?

Comment: I think you have mistaken `prevState` for meaning that react can somehow dig up past states from when the handler was previously called. But that's not what that argument does -- it's just a capture of the variables at the current time. The word "previous" is really in relation to that "the current state, which is going to be before the next one". If you want to track states prior to that you'd need new structures to store them, and that'd be something you would have to implement.

Comment: @adsy Thanks a lot, I really wanted to get the past state. How bad will it be if I save the past state in this.state.prevData. And is there a better way to implement it?

Comment: Hi @jafonin, Going through your comments I would suggest you implement an array/prevValue variable, where you could push values to it and maintain previous values.

Comment: Also, any reason you are working with class components ?

Comment: Hi @Mahesh, I wanted to use componentDidMount, so I'm working with classes

Comment: On a different note: 
If you haven't tried that, `componentDidMount` can also be achieved via `useEffect`. You can view https://stackoverflow.com/a/56249248/16576319. This will help reduce complexities and more developers will be able to assist you along the way as functional approach is more prominent.

Comment: @Mahesh, Im also use PureComponent, Is there a way to use it in functional component?

Comment: @jafonin, I would suggest you to raise it as different StackOverflow question altogether as I need further input on that. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Answer (score 0):

prevState will not give you the state of the last render, but if the current one. If you want to persist state you should use a ref or a custom hook.